# No other way to save entities in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's consider following situation: I have entity User. User has some fields to save in database and one-to-one relation with UserInfo. Whenever i save object of User to the database, UserInfo won't be saved. Is there a way to fix this? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to cascade the persist/update/delete from User to UserInfo.  Something like: 
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)

There's multiple values of CascadeType, so make sure to use the one that does what you want.